# Spring3 MVC - how to impliment CRUD correctly on the same controller?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3

I am trying to create simple CRUD controller and view using Spring mvc.
I am able to:
Get the document list
Upload document
Deleted Document

If I would like to send the request using FORM,

How do i implement Download Document?

Should I use  for every document?
Another thing - am i using the MVC framework correctly?

```
<html>
<body>  

<!-- the list: -->
<c:forEach items="${documentList}" var="documentRow"> 
    <Generate table here>

<!-- upload part -->
<form:form modelAttribute="uploadDocument"  method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <form:input path="fileData" type="file"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="actUploadocument" name="action" value="uploadDocument" />
</form:form>

<!-- delete part -->
<form:form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="documentId" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="actUploadocument" name="action" value="deleteDocument" />
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

The CRUD controller?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/documents")
public class DocumentsController 
{ 
@Autowired
private MainService mainService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listDocuments(Model model) {
    List<Document> docs = mainService.getAllDocuments();        
    model.addAttribute("documentList",docs);
    model.addAttribute(new UploadDocument());
    return "admin/documents";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST , params="action=uploadDocument")  
public String uploadDocument(UploadDocument uploadDocument){
    savedocument(uploadDocument);
    return "redirect:/admin/documents.do";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST , params="action=removeDocument")  
public String removeDocument(@RequestParam(value="documentId", required=true) String documentId){
    savedocument(documentId);
    return "redirect:/admin/documents.do";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST , params="action=downloadDocument")  
public String downloadDocument(@RequestParam(value="documentId", required=true) String documentId,
                            HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response ) {
    writeDocToResponse(documentId,response);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think your controller looks fine. It's basically down to taste and religion but this works for me.

Comment: What is the best practice of the download document from the view side (JSP)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you need to open *file download dialog* is a set response properties to identify HTTPresponce as *attachment*.
For instance:

```
response.reset();
response.setContentType(getYourFileContentType());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\""+getYourFileName()+"\"");
```

Then you may call your service method to stream file.

Comment: Also it should be a get method handler! Just use POST to send FORM data to controller only.

Comment: Thank you monsieur, I know how to write the object to the response,
The method **writeDocToResponse** does that..